# How to proxy setup nginx with play and angularjs

Tags: nginx, proxy, port

I am learning play framework and angularjs with nginx. The play app is running on port **9090** and angularjs app is running on **9000**. I am trying to proxy all requests to `/app/*` to the back-end Play application I had tried some nginx config with less success. Below is the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file i tried.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000; 
    } 

    location /app {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get this to work?

Comment: did you try moving "location /app" before "location / "